# Building yaml-cpp with cmake and visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cmake, yaml-cpp

I am trying to build yaml-cpp with cmake and visual studio 2010  in Windows.
First I open the file in cmake using the gui-tool, configure and generate. 
A visual studio solution is generated in the build-folder specified. 
Then I open the solution in vs10 and build it. 
Some folders are generated but I can't find any binaries or anything to include in my project. 
I am not used to c++ or visual studio so this is outside of my comfort zone. 
Can someone please point me in the right direction as of how to get the yaml-cpp library working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic Pebkac. After a good nights sleep I found the file in the project. 
libyaml-cppmdd.lib was generated in the Debug folder. I had forgotten to add .lib to the file ending while adding the file to Additional dependencies to the Linker. Therefore the Linker thought it was a .obj file and complained.

Answer (score 1):

According to `CMakeLists.txt`, you should have `yaml-cpp.dll` at the root of your binary dir (the dir which you used to configure build).

You can try running install target.